# Mailchimp API merge fields - date format

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using the Mailchimp API to add a new member.

I have defined a custom merge field called `ADDED` which is the date I added this member to the list. I want this field to be required when submitting it via the API. I defined it as `DD/MM/YYYY` format (see below):

[image]

This is what my json string looks like:

```
{
    "email_address":"email@server.com", 
    "status":"subscribed", 
    "merge_fields": 
         {"USERLEVEL":"1", "BATCH":"999000", "ADDED":"21/04/2020"}
}
```

As you can see, my format is indeed `dd/mm/yyyy', but when submitting the API request, I get this error message:

`**Your merge fields were invalid: Please enter the date**`

```
{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
"title":"Invalid Resource","status":400,
"detail":"Your merge fields were invalid.",
"instance":"1ad6bc0e-7728-45c1-a308-b751247efb5b",
"errors":[{"field":"ADDED","message":"Please enter the date"}]}
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error, when I do seem to have the correctly formatted date in the request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems that the definition of the field as `DD/MM/YYYY` might only be for reading purposes. but for submitting, it must be done like this:

`"ADDED":"2020-04-21T00:00:00.001Z"`

Comment: I also was able to use date format MM/DD/YYYY as well as your format without time (2020-04-21T).